# Inheriting a class that modifies properties of child class get overwritten

Tags: javascript, inheritance

So this is the simplest version of the issue I could come up with. I understand why its happening but I don't know the best way to go about fixing it.

```
class TestParent {
    variableA = ""

    constructor(data) {
        for(const key in data) {
            this[key] = data[key]
        }
    }
}

class Test extends TestParent {
    variableB = ""
}
```

When I try this code...

```
let test = new Test({"variableB": "something"})

// Expected {"variableA": "", "variableB": "something"}
// Got      {"variableA": "", "variableB": ""}
```

Now if I remove `variableB` from `Test` class then the code works just fine. From what I gather from my code is that `TestParent`'s constructor is doing it's job but once `Test`'s constructor is called it overwrites the property with the default one stored in the proto?

How do I go about saving what is done in the `TestParent` constructor. Instead of defining the property in the class scope do I just need to define it in the constructor itself? Am I missing a keyword to add to that property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `variableB: 'something'` not to be overwritten, you should alter the section of the code which assigns to `variableB`, in `Test`. Assign the empty string to `variableB` only if the property doesn't already exist yet:

```
variableB = this.variableB || ''
```

```js
class TestParent {
  variableA = ""

  constructor(data) {
    for (const key in data) {
      this[key] = data[key];
    }
  }
}

class Test extends TestParent {
  variableB = this.variableB || ''
}
const test = new Test({
  variableB: "something"
});
console.log(test);
```

(or, if you want to preserve falsey values too, `variableB = this.variableB === undefined ? '' : this.variableB`)

Comment: OK, I think i understand what javascript does with constructors. It copies the value from the prototype to the instance after it runs all the supers. Thanks for you're help I appreciate it.